# Doctrine Rollback Issue

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, virtuemart

I have a weird phenomenom. I added database tables to the schema which are already existing in the database the connect 'virtuemart'. But he can't connect to this tables.

I tried it with

```
    $taxId = Doctrine::getTable('JosVmTaxRate')
        ->findOneBy('tr.tax_country', 'NZL');
```

and

```
    $taxId = Doctrine::getTable('JosVmTaxRate')
        ->findBy('tr.tax_country', 'NZL');
```

and

```
    $taxId = Doctrine::getTable('JosVmTaxRate')
        ->findOneBy('tr.tax_country', '"NZL"');
```

and

```
    $taxId = Doctrine::getTable('JosVmTaxRate')
        ->createQuery('tr')
        ->addWhere('tr.tax_country =?', 'NZL')
        ->execute()
        ->get(0);
```

but always the error message

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Transaction_Exception 
Rollback failed. There is no active transaction.
```

appears.

I checked the schema but I can't find any fault in there:

```
JosVmTaxRate:
  columns:
    tax_rate_id:                    { type: int, notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    vendor_id                       { type: int, default: null }
    tax_state                       { type: string(64), default: null }
    tax_country                     { type: string(64), default: null }
    mdate                           { type: int, default: null }
    tax_rate                        { type: decimal(10), scale(4), default: null }
```

Any idea?

I hope I provided enough information. If not don't hesitate and ask for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks alright for me, but the schema not.

1. What about the colons after `vendor_id`, `tax_state`, `tax_country`, `mdate` and `tax_rate`? They are missing.
2. `scale(4)` is wrong. `scale: 4` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for that! I must be blind!